# How can I change textColor of android.R.id.text1?

Tags: android

I want change color of listview's item, but I don't know how access android.R.id.text1.

If anyone know change android.R.id.text1's color, please help me.

Comment: it is not possible. instead you can use your own textview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it with following custom XML

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/tvName"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:padding="5dp"
              android:textColor="your_color"
              android:text="Your_text" />
```

You can set Padding as per your need. For Ur Reference [Example_Of_Custom_listview](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html)

Answer (score 0):

Please refer below link.

[custom List view](http://androidexample.com/How_To_Create_A_Custom_Listview_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=67&aaid=92)

In that,  there is a method as "getView" in CustomAdapter class...

In that method, U can change color.
**or**

You can also change from xml file as below:

```
android:textColor="yourcolor"
```